# React - Wrapping dev onClick handler triggered before inner checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, onclicklistener

I have a div with an onClick handler that navigates to a subpage when clicking on it. However, there is also a [Checkbox](https://elemefe.github.io/element-react/index#/en-US/checkbox) for selection contained in this div with a onChange handler.

**Expected behavior**: the checkbox onChange handler is triggered first and I can stop the propagation to the wrapping div's event handler.

**Actual behavior**: the div's event handler is triggered first and through navigating to a subpage, the checkbox's handler isn't executed at all.

How can I solve this?

```
const onClick = () => props.history.push({ pathname: `/mySubpage/${resource._id}` });

const onCheckbox = (e) => {
    // this should prevent the onClick handler to be triggered
    e.stopPropagation();
    setIsSelected(!isSelected);
}

<div onClick={onClick}>
    ...
    <Checkbox onChange={onCheckbox}/>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: @keikai will add it in a couple of mins

Comment: Have you tried testing once with actual `<input type="checkbox"` instead of `<Checkbox />`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setTimeOut if no then please try it...... 
onClick = () => { setTimeOut(()=>  props.history.push({ pathname: `/mySubpage/${resource._id}` }),100); } 
// i think it should work because it will delay props.history.push() method and in that the other whole javascript will be rendered and at the end your div onclick method will be completee.
Otherwise set any dummy state after settime out